# How can I find the first element's method result that is not null?

Tags: kotlin

So I have parsers and want to use the first that does return a non-null value. How would I do that most elegantly?

```
return parsers.map { it.parse(content) }.firstOrNull { it != null }
```

would map all (million?) parsers before picking the first.

```
return parsers.firstOrNull { it.parse(content) != null }?.parse(content)
```

would run the (expensive?) `parse()` once again.

I know I can

```
for (parser in parsers) {
    val result = parser.parse(content)
    if (result != null) {
        return result
    }
}
return null
```

```
parsers.forEach { it.parse(content)?.run { return this } }
return null
```

is the shortest I can get but it's not nice to read.

I'm pretty sure there is a shortcut here that I don't see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a sequence. It makes your computation lazy, so that you will only compute `parse` as many times as you need.

```
return parsers.asSequence()
              .map { it.parse(content) }
              .find { it != null }
```

Comment: Awesome! Definitely sequences are missing in my toolbox. I'll give the others until tomorrow to come up with something to beat this but I like it already for the tool I was missing.

Comment: I ended up using @gromyk's solution for being slightly shorter and more explicit about not throwing if `it != null` wasn't fulfilled but as you were the first to come up with sequences and actually explained stuff, your answer it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the overhead of a `Sequence`, or mapping lots of values unnecessarily, you could use an extension method such as:

```
inline fun <T, R> List<T>.firstMappedNotNull(transform: (T) -> R): R? {
    for (e in this)
        return transform(e) ?: continue
    return null
}
```

This uses the minimum of mapping function calls and temporary objects.  It's necessarily written in an imperative way, but it's quite short, and makes your own code short, clear, and functional.

(This version returns `null` if the list was empty or every mapping returned `null`.  You could of course change the signature and last line to throw an exception instead.)

It's a shame this function isn't already in the standard library.  But it's easy to add your own!

Comment: ...short, clear and functional... but not for the function implementation itself ;-) that `continue` takes precedence over `return` if `transform(e)` results in `null`? this, although you accept `(T) -> R`? using the elvis-operator to fallback? ;-) ...but I like that you omitted the `Sequence` ;-)

Comment: I think the naming is the biggest problem for such a function. Moreover, as soon as you make it more generic (e.g. accepting a predicate instead of assuming that everyone wants to return the first mapped non-null-value) it becomes more cumbersome to use... `inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.findMapped(transform : (T) -> R?, predicate : (R?) -> Boolean) : R?`? ... with `inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.findMappedNotNull(transform : (T) -> R?) = findMapped(transform) { it != null }`? hmmm.... except you overload all the needed functions...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For a one-off thing it's overkill but I'll keep it in mind if the pattern returns.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use the following code:

```
parsers.asSequence()
    .mapNotNull { it.parse(content) }
    .first()
```